# For an object in a rotating cylinder, is the normal force on that object equal to the centripetal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, centripetal-force

There is a vertical cylinder, an object is glued to the wall (verticle) of that cylinder. The cylinder starts rotating. Is the normal force, in this scenario, the centripetal force?

I ask this question based on the information that, when planets are rotating, the gravitational force is equal to the centripetal force between the two planets.

Is this concept valid when applied in the context of a rotating vertical cylinder with an object glued on its wall?

Comment: Are there any other options for what the centripetal force could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The centripetal force is just a name given to whatever causes the inwards/radial pull. So, it is just a name given to the sum of all forces (or force components) that are directed radially towards the centre. In different scenarios, the centripetal force is therefore made up of one or more different forces. I you scenario, it is the normal force from the wall.